# How to solve this else syntax error in python

Tags: python, function, syntax-error, fibonacci

Following is this code for generating Fibonacci series for n elements,
the else which has a comment is the part that is causing an error

```
def solve(n):
# write your code here,end=
a=[0,1]
b=[]
if n==0:
    b.append(0)
return b    
else:#THE ERROR PART
    for i in range(n-1):
        a.append(a[i+1]+a[i])
    return a
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is highly recommended to post text information like code, logs and errors as a text not images. It helps other users to find and answer your question.

Comment: @ashy, Please always indent the code before posting, it makes the code more readable to the others. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indent for `return` needs correction.

```
def solve(n):
    # write your code here,end=
    a=[0,1]
    b=[]
    if n==0:
        b.append(0)
        return b    #edit here
    else:#THE ERROR PART -> no more error
        for i in range(n-1):
            a.append(a[i+1]+a[i])
        return a

solve(10)
```

Output

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `return` statement above `else` should be indented inside the `if` statement. It is currently outside the `if` statement.

```
def solve(n):
# write your code here,end=
a=[0,1]
b=[]
if n==0:
    b.append(0)
    return b    //update here
else:#THE ERROR PART
    for i in range(n-1):
        a.append(a[i+1]+a[i])
    return a
```

Answer (score 0):

Mind the indentation as the return on line 8, just exits the program making the else irrevelant

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is highly recommended to post text information like code, logs and errors as a text not images.